# Making a timestamp from date and time

Tags: java, swing, date, jspinner

I am taking date input using jdatepicker :

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
final JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);
datePicker.setBounds(200,430,140,40);
```

I am taking time input using JSpinner :

```
final JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner();
SpinnerDateModel spinnermodel = new SpinnerDateModel();
spinnermodel.setCalendarField(Calendar.MINUTE);
spinner1.setModel(spinnermodel);
final JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner1,"hh:mm");
spinner1.setEditor(de);
```

How should i set them to make a timestamp which is to be entered in the MS Access Database.

Comment: See the class java.util.Calendar. It has all method to merge two Date object and then you can create a Timestamp: new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis())

Comment: i want to enter my own time and date ...  how can i do that ...  and then making a time stamp

Comment: [SpinnerDateModel.getDate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html#getDate%28%29)?

Comment: I want user to enter the date... and time please explain .. i am not that familiar with Spinner class

Comment: You could call `getDate()` on your `SpinnerDateModel` and format this `Date` with a `SimpleDateFormat` to the Timestamp you want. And you'll need only the `JSpinner`, because you can enter Date and Time with this `Component`.

Comment: After getting the date from the getDate method , how to make the timestamp